# why does the site say an existing tag can't be created with this low a reputation?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

for my first question i tried tagging it `nwod` (for new world of darkness) and `changeling`. The system tutut-ed at me saying that i couldn't create new tags with a reputation this low.

Fair enough for the `changeling` and `nwod` tag, but then i tried `wod`, and no luck either, even though i can find 5 questions tagged this way...

so, bug, or feature i don't get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the canonical tag is [world-of-darkness] and those other tags have been largely retired for that one.  I don't see anything tagged [wod], and [wod] has been defined as a synonym for [world-of-darkness].  Does seem like a bug that it tells you "you can't create a tag" in that situation though.

Comment: well i assure you there were some content tagged with it, but perhaps it has been changed since then. in my experience the stack is quick on its feet :)